# How to create a simple three dimensional coordinate display?

Tags: three.js

I have a series of data that simply represents X/Y/Z coordinates, and would like to  display them on screen.  I am aware of the existence of three.js, but the examples I have waded through so far seem to be for far more complex animations and whatnot, and have not managed to find an ELI5 tutorial of set of documentation to get me going.

Note that I am not married to three.js, but it does seem like the best tool for the job.

I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, just some links to some basic documentation would be so very appreciated!

Comment: [https://threejs.org/docs](https://threejs.org/docs) or [https://threejsfundamentals.org](https://threejsfundamentals.org)

Comment: I was aware oft he location of the docs.  They start off at a higher level, doing way more than I need.  I don't need shapes, animation, etc.  I'm just looking to plot points.

Comment: If it was me I'd look at **all** [the examples](https://threejs.org/examples/) and any [one](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_buffergeometry_points) [that](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_custom_attributes_points2) [looked](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_custom_attributes_points3) [close](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_points_waves) to "[plotting](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_interactive_raycasting_points) [points](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_points_dynamic)" I'd go look in the code and see how they specify the points

Comment: In fact in the docs I'd click the search area at the top and type "Points" which would lead [these docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial) which seem to lead to many examples.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions.  I think that plot.ly may be a better resource for what I'm trying to do; three.js feels like trying to kill a fly with a tactical nuke.  

https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-point-clustering/

Comment: This is super easy my friend, use Three.js... I will add an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

**Straightforward, conceptually consists of making sphere's and setting their position to your coordinates.**

1) Have coordinate data

```
const coordData = [ 
    {x: 9, y: 2, z: 6},
    {x: 3, y: 7, z: 4},
    ...
]
```

2) Create Geometry, Material and Group

```
const pointGeom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 5, 32, 32 ),
      pointMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 }),
      pointGroup = new THREE.Group();
```

3) Loop over coordinate data and create a point (sphere) for each using above const's

```
for (var i = coordData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   const coord = coordData[i],
         point = new THREE.Mesh( pointGeom, pointMat );

   point.position.set( coord.x, coord.y, coord.z );
   pointGroup.add(point);
}
```

4) Add Group to your scene

```
scene.add(pointGroup);
```

Comment: Michael, I appreciate the thoughtful reply.  I had given up on three.js as my solution, but what you lay out here does seem pretty simple.  I'll see if I can grab a "hello world" implementation of three.js, then use your suggestion here.  

I'll follow up and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well, rats.  I do get some spheres from this, but it doesn't help me a lot.  This is nigh ideal - https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-point-clustering/.  It gives me data points with a sense of meaning, what with the x/y/z lines in place for reference.I just cannot seem to recreate it.

Comment: Hmm well you could create axis lines...https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Line and https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Drawing-lines would be the correct start in the docs and then creating text objects would be here...https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TextGeometry

Comment: I think it comes down to how badly you want to use Three.js. I understand naturally that ANY new framework or technology is difficult at first to use. I find a lot of enjoyment in having become halfway decent at using it though. I think this project you could accomplish within a day despite not having used Three.js before...with proficiency about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with a great answer through the plot.ly library.  This page was pretty much perfect for what I wanted to do.

https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-point-clustering/